# Flink: Error executing pipeline java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]

Tags: java, batch-processing, apache-flink

I am using `Flink v1.4.0`.

I am leveraging `Flink`'s native Graph API (Gelly), which I am using to process 12 million data points (edges). I am currently running my jobs through `IntelliJ` using the `Flink` minicluster which executes all TaskManagers and the JobManager in the same JVM.

As I load the data, effectively generating my edges, just before I get my `Flink` job to run, I am always presented with the following exception:

```
...
Connected to JobManager at Actor[akka://flink/user/jobmanager_1#XXXXXXXXXX] with leader session id XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX.
322062 [main] ERROR com.somecompany.some.domain.name.some.javaClass- Error executing pipeline
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
            at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:223)
            at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:157)
            at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:169)
            at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:169)
            at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
```

...

I made sure to edit the run configuration through `IntelliJ` to add:

```
-Dakka.client.timeout:600s
-Dakka.ask.timeout:600s
```

but the exceptions persists, and I have no other clue as to what is causing it. When I reduce the data size everything works fine.

Same problem appears when I try to submit the same job through the `Flink UI` to run on a local version of `Flink` I have installed on the cluster. In this case, the job never starts and I am not even able to preview the automatically generated DAG of operators. Again the problem goes away when I reduce the amount of data to be processed. I have also, updated the `flink-conf.yaml` to include the same `akka` configuration properties but that made no difference.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running a Flink job within IntelliJ, one relies on the Flink mini-cluster. The mini-cluster differs from running Flink on Standalone, Yarn or Mesos, in the sense that it relies on a single JVM. In addition, the mini-cluster is pre-configured in many ways and altering that configuration is not always possible (at least with respect to some settings).

One thing that I had to change when submitting my jobs to the cluster (not when running them through the mini-cluster) was the size of the heap memory I was allocating to the Job-Manager. This was necessary because loading the data to be processing was not part of the Flink job I wanted to run (which is not standard practice in Flink and it is actually wrong to do anything like this). By increasing the Job-Manager's heap I was able to get my jobs to run but eventually I had to define a new input format for my Flink Job's in order to save the Job-Manager from having to pre-load the data for execution--it should not be its responsibility anyway.

To the question at hand: this allocation of heap-memory to the job-manager cannot be done (as far as I am aware) through IntelliJ, and therefore jobs will always fail.